# How do I validate my YAML file from command line?

Tags: yaml

I am having issues pulling from a YAML config file:

> Fatal error: while parsing a block mapping; expected <block end>, but found block entry

While there are plenty of online YAML validators, which I have tried and have helped, I'd like to validate my YAML files from the command line and integrate this into my continuous integration pipeline.

Comment: and
http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

Comment: Try: `travis lint .travis.yml`

Comment: `python -c "from yaml import load, Loader; load(open('.travis.yml'), Loader=Loader)"`

Comment: sudo pip install PyYAML will ensure a module is loaded.

Comment: @targnation That validator gives examples from the 1.2 specification (from 2009), but cannot  parse valid YAML1.2 like e.g.`0o52` correctly. This because the tool is PyYAML based and can only handle a subset of YAML 1.1 (from 2005). So use with caution.

Comment: This question should not be closed. Perhaps re-word it to "How do I validate my YAML file from command line". This is a valid and useful question

Comment: Seconded @hanxue - This comes up as the first result when searching the topic and should be a useful reference when google lands us here.

Comment: Yeah, this question should not be closed.  I don't think the answers are opinionated or spam.

Comment: I think it does depend on what you're trying to validate. For CircleCI, steps can be found here: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/local-cli/#validating-20-yaml-syntax

Comment: Newer solutions now exist such as [yamllint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: The question is closed by a reason, and the reason is still valid. (Currently there are 4 deleted link-only answers). Having each answer to be a reference to a nice tool is good... but how is this better than a search engine provides?

Answer (score 198):

With basic Ruby installation this should work:

```bash
ruby -ryaml -e "p YAML.load(STDIN.read)" < data.yaml
```

Python version (thx @Murphy):

```bash
pip install pyyaml
python -c 'import yaml, sys; print(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin))' < data.yaml
```

Comment: If you remove the `puts y` from the end of this then you get a more standard UNIX behavior: if the file is valid then nothing will be printed, and if it’s invalid then you’ll see an exception and stack trace.

Comment: …and if you remove the `puts y` you can also get rid of the `y=`.

Comment: And if you're really just using this as part of a ci test pipeline, then there's no need for `puts` at all. Return code is simply `0` if valid, else non-zero and you'll get a exception stack trace. Reduces noise on the CLI output if you're even looking at it.

Comment: If you use the following: `ruby -e "require 'yaml';puts YAML.load_file(ARGV[0])"` you can then pass the filename in after, instead of needing to edit the snippet directly.

Comment: `python -c 'import yaml, sys; yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin)' < data.yaml` for python enthusiasts..

Comment: `python3 -c 'import yaml, sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin))' < data.yaml`

Pretty prints

Comment: How can one put @Murphy's command in a pre-commit hook? I only want my pre-commit hook to print out the stacktrace in case of an error and nothing else on success

Comment: The python version also works with a normal text file

Answer (score 44):

You could use [yamllint](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint#installation). It's available in Homebrew, etc. It can be used for syntax validation as well as for linting.

Answer (score 33):

To correct your `.yaml` files I recommend the tool yamllint. It can be launched easily from the local console.

The package `yamllint` is available for all major operating systems.

It's installable from the system's package sources. (e.g. `sudo apt-get install yamllint`).
[See documentation for quick start and installation.](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)

Comment: `yamllint` by default calls a lot of things "errors" which are actually perfectly acceptable.  e.g. line too long, or "wrong" indentation.  I'm sure it's customizable to fix these, but it's too picky for a lot of common use-cases.

Answer (score 30):

Given that you have a perl install on the server you are working on, and it has some of the basic YAML tools, you can use...

```
perl -MYAML -e 'use YAML;YAML::LoadFile("./file.yaml")'
```

It should be noted that this will be strict in it's interpretation of the file, but useful.

Comment: Can't locate YAML.pm

Comment: /usr/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'install YAML'

Comment: probably a problem with CPAN installation but: `Can't locate object method "install" via package "YAML" at -e line 1.`

Comment: If the above doesn't work you can always try: `perl -MCPAN -e 'shell'` and then at the command line do `install YAML`

Answer (score 4):

Use the **yq** tool!

```
yq eval your.yaml
```

It also displays all the values, you can suppress that by redirecting the output (anyway errors will be displayed):

```
yq eval your.yaml > /dev/null
```

Install yq tool:

- MacOS:
  brew install yq
- Linux:
  snap brew install yq

More on the **yq GitHub page** (including Windows binaries): https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

Answer (score 1):

```
yamllint -d "{extends: default, rules: {quoted-strings: disable, line-length: disable}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferd way is using yamllint (`pip install yamllint`)

`yamllint -d "{extends: default, rules: {quoted-strings: enable}}" .`

Since I really want to catch quote errors,
e.g.   `validate: bash -c ' ' \""`

This is valid yaml, since yaml will just quote the string and turn it into:
  `validate: "bash -c ' ' \\\"\""`

Whilst there was just clearly a quote missing at the beginning of the validate comand.

So a normal yaml checker will not detect this, yamllint wil not even detect this in it's default configuration, so turn on quoted-strings checker.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [yaml-lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-lint) that depends on Node.JS:

- installation (CLI): `npm install -g yaml-lint`
- usage: `yamllint file.yaml`

Answer (score -5):

If you got no interpreter installed in your environment but still got a *curl*, then you could use an online linter project like [Lint-Trilogy](https://github.com/berndkuennen/lint_trilogy):

```
curl -X POST  --data "data=$(cat myfile.yml)" https://www.lint-trilogy.com/lint/yaml/json
```

It delivers the validation result incl. error descriptions (if any) as json or csv or, where sufficient, as plain text *true* or *false*.

It's available as docker file, too. So if you often need a REST based linter, perhaps in a CI/CD pipeline, it may be handy to host an own instance on your site.

Comment: Exporting your yaml to a third party requires a lot of trust in that third party

Comment: That's right, and that's why the linter is open source and runable as docker container on your own notebook. Github repo: https://github.com/berndkuennen/lint_trilogy

Comment: It work for me. This is easy way how to fight with spaces and tabs in netplan configuration

Answer (score -12):

Or alternately installed (free) Eclipse IDE and then YEdit yaml editor and see your yaml with syntax highlighting, error flags, and outline views. One time setup cost works pretty well for me.

Comment: OP specifically asked for CLI solutions.